# CoreData predicate for one to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many

I have two entity: A and B.
Every element of A can have more elements of B (one to many).

Now I have an item of A and I would to take, in this item, one item B (contained in A) that it  has B.field = "myParameter".

How can I generate the Predicate for this?

Comment: You may be looking for that (tested with *MagicalRecord*): `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(field LIKE %@) AND (isLinkedToAObject == %@), myFieldParameter, objectA];`With: `ClassB` has a property `isLinkedToAObject` to link it to `ClassA`.

Comment: @Larme, if you would to insert your comment as an answer, I can mark the question as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for that (tested with *MagicalRecord*):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(field LIKE %@) AND (isLinkedToAObject == %@)", myFieldParameter, objectA];
```

With:
`ClassB` has a property `isLinkedToAObject` to link it to `ClassA`.