# Core Data Fetch Request Relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, relationship

I want to fetch objects B which has a to-many relationship with object A (ie. A -->> B)
this is my [Core Data graph](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8145391250/Relationship.png)

and i want when i select a group in "group View Controller", open all members of selected group in "Contact view controller", [like here](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8145392126/Untitled.png)

Comment: Something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930232/coredata-predicate-for-one-to-many-relationship/25931652#25931652 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the "contacts view controller" a property of type `Group` (the group that is selected in the list of groups) - let's call it `group`. If you use a `UITableView` you should use a `NSFetchedResultsController` that should include a sort descriptor (e.g. alphabetical by name) and the following predicate:

```
NSPredicate(format: "group = %@", group)
```

*NB: in your object graph you are using an illogical plural when naming your entity `Contacts` instead of the more plausible `Contact`.*